# call paint event an other form

Tags: c#, graphic

I want to call paint event from an other form
This is my Form 1

```
public void Draw(int a,int b)
    {
        Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black,2);
        gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(a, b), new Point(b, a));
    }
```

And  when i want to call Draw Event from form 2 with this code

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Draw(20,40);
        f.Show();
```

but it doesn't work
How i can call draw event from an other form?
Thank You

Comment: Best practices aside, I think your immediate problem might be because f.show() comes after f.Draw()

Comment: You don't really want to do this.  You want to communicate between the forums (via events are some other mechanism), pass data around with minimal coupling, and let the form handle its own painting.